# Result of $\sum_{k=-N}^N \exp(i k \theta)$

Tags: calculus, summation

I have aquestion to find
$$\sum_{k=-N}^N \exp(i k \theta)$$
The answer given is: $$\frac{\sin(N+1/2)\theta}{\sin(\theta/2)}$$

My attempt:
$$\sum_{k=0}^N \exp(i k \theta)=\frac{\sin((N+1)/2)\theta}{\sin(\theta/2)} \exp(i k \theta/2)$$

Questions:

1. Does $\sum_{k=-N}^N \exp(i k \theta)=\sum_{k=0}^{2N} \exp(i k \theta)$?

   - If this is the case, we could have: 
     $$\sum_{k=-N}^N \exp(i k \theta)=\frac{\sin(N+1/2)\theta}{\sin(\theta/2)} \exp(i k \theta)$$
2. Even with a Yes to question one, we are still away from the result. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=-N}^N \exp(i k \theta)$$

Substitute $k\mapsto k-N$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2N} \exp(i (k-N) \theta)=\sum_{k=0}^{2N} \exp(ik\theta-iN\theta)\\=
\sum_{k=0}^{2N} \exp(ik\theta)/\exp(iN\theta)=\frac{1}{\exp(iN\theta)}\sum_{k=0}^{2N} \exp(ik\theta)$$

$$=\frac{1}{\exp(iN\theta)}\sum_{k=0}^{2N} \exp(i\theta)^k$$

Comment: This is the hint I am looking for, crystal clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\zeta = e^{i\theta}$.  Then the given series is $$S_n = \sum_{k=-n}^n \zeta^k = \zeta^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \zeta^k.$$  This is a finite geometric series with common ratio $\zeta$, and therefore has value $$S_n = \zeta^{-n} \frac{\zeta^{2n+1} - 1}{\zeta - 1} = \frac{\zeta^{n+1} - \zeta^{-n}}{\zeta - 1} = \frac{\zeta^{n+1/2} - \zeta^{-n-1/2}}{\zeta^{1/2} - \zeta^{-1/2}}.$$  Now it is trivial to observe the desired result using $$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$

Comment: How do you come up with: $$\sum_{k=-n}^n \zeta^k = \zeta^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \zeta^k.$$

Comment: Ok, got it, explained by Kamilo9875

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=-N}^N \exp(i k \theta)= \exp(-iN\theta)\frac{1-\exp(i(2N+1)\theta)}{1-\exp(i\theta)}=\frac{\exp(-iN\theta-\exp(i(N+1)\theta))}{1-\exp(i\theta)}$$
$$\frac{\exp(-i(N+1/2)\theta)-\exp(i(N+1/2)\theta)}{\exp(-i\theta/2)-\exp(i\theta/2)}$$
$$=\frac{-2i\sin((N+1/2)\theta)}{-2i\sin(\theta/2)}$$
$$\frac{\sin((N+1/2)\theta)}{\sin(\theta/2)}$$